# IF statement does not perform the condition (bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

this is the bash code:

```
FILE=`cat /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt | grep -o changed`

if [  "$FILE" = "changed"  ]; then
    echo "sending mail $send"
else
    echo "fingerprint has not changed"
fi
```

the problem is that the email is sent even if the word "changed" not exist in the file2.txt
what the problem with the condition ?

Comment: Try to debug, add `set -x` after the shebang or run you script with `bash -x ./myscript` to see the output.

Comment: The cat is useless there. `grep -q change /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt || exit` Should exit the script if nothing found.

Comment: If there are multiply "changed" is in your file then the output of grep command is not a "changed" it probably "changed changed changed changed, .." you can use -m1 switch to get just the first matched string: `cat /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt | grep -o -m1 changed`

Comment: hi Jetchisel , i did what you suggest , the line "sending mail" not exist in output but the mail is sent anyway ..and the second suggest (with grep) still sent email

Comment: hi Alireza, there is only 1 "change" in the expected string

Comment: @yishai, then you need to examine the output of `set -x` thoroughly.

Comment: @yishai can you provide the output of your file2.txt?

Comment: You could insert the line `declare -p FILE` after the first line to see exactly what, if anything, is being found. Also, you can streamline the if statement to: `if grep -q changed  /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt; then`. The `if` statement checks the exit code of *any* command that follows it (`[` is actually a command!). `grep -q ...` will quietly return 0 (true) if it finds the string.

Comment: @yishai : Aside from the fact, that your way of testing the condition is somewhat odd and unreliable, the behaviour you are describing can not exist.  I'm pretty sure that, if the condition is true, you **do** have the string _changed_ (maybe not as a word, but as part of some larger word) somewhere in your file. Try to create for debugging a small example for `file2.txt` manually, maybe just a couple of line.

Comment: @yishai : For debugging, I would put a `grep -n changed /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt` after the `then`. When you get _sending mail_, you see the line where grep thinks that the word occurs, including its number.

Comment: To avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/useless-use-of-cat/) and to make the matching work with any number of matches, you may want to consider `if grep -q changed /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt; then ...; else ...; fi`.

Comment: @Alireza i checked the output ( -x) , i see empty line , probably where in the place that "sending mail' was

Comment: @Alireza this is the output of file2.txt: dc01 Fingerprint are match, dc02 Fingerprint are match . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:
the "send" variable that exist above in my script (I didn't post it in my QA) sent the email anyway, without even arriving to IF statement, I don't know why it is like that , but when I put the send command (sendmail) **into** the IF statement.. the email was **not** sent, of course I simulate situation that the word "changed" exist and the email was sent

many thanks to all the helpers

```
FILE=`cat /home/_nonlocl/file2.txt | grep -o changed`

if [  "$FILE" = "changed"  ]; then
    `echo -e sendmail -s bla bla bla....` 
else
    echo "fingerprint has not changed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
send="SOMETHING"

if [[ $(grep -wc "changed" file2.txt) -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "sending mail $send"
else
    echo "fingerprint has not changed"
fi
```

- `grep -w` ensures that only the word "changed", without any other character before or after it is considered.  "itchanged" or "changed123" will not trigger the email.
- `grep -c` will only return something.  0 if not there, some number > 0 if it is there.
- You did not mention the value of `$send`, so I put something.